# docker-machine specify daemon port

Tags: docker, docker-machine

Cannot I specify which port the docker-daemon listens to when connecting via docker-machine? I couldn't find such option in ~/.docker/machine/machines/name/config.json

I mean, docker daemon on some machine is listening on 1234 instead 2376, cannot I connect to it via docker-machine?

Comment: P.S. I have generic driver there, docker daemon runs on real machine

Comment: Is this a programming question or a configuration question?